# Duplicate folder finder

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, duplicate-files

Anyone know a free duplicate finder app for Windows that will find duplicate folders? I want to be able to select a drive and it will return all folders on this drive that are duplicates based on the files they contain.

Should compare by file/ext name and size, content checking is not needed.

Anything free would be ok - even if free trial.

Comment: I know CCleaner (which is free) has a "Duplicate Finder" feature.  Never really used it, and not sure if it's simply for individual files, or if it'll check full directories.  In CCleaner, it's in the "Tools" menu.